# Chrome extension style not being injected

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome-extension

I've written an extension for chrome that adds certain functionality to the site 'reddit'. It adds an extra button to each post on the site with the following jQuery:

```
...    
$(this).append('<li><span class="grab_button">grab</span></li>');
...
```

The class `grab_button` is new. It does not exist in the reddit stylesheets, but the CSS in the extension stylesheet chrome is supposed to load is not being applied:

```
html body span.grab_button {
        color: #888 !important;
        font-weight: bold !important;
        padding: 0 1px !important;
}
```

I have added the `!important` rules to make sure any CSS that would apply is overridden. I've made the definition very specific (I could probably make it more specific, but I shouldn't have to). Why on earth isn't it being applied? If I use the webkit developer tools to inspect the added button, it lists all the styles that apply to it, even ones that are being overridden, but it does not show my custom one.

Here is the relevent section of the manifest:

```
"content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["http://www.reddit.com/*"],
            "js": ["jquery-2.0.3.min.js", "script.js"],
        "css": ["style.css"]
        }
],

"web_accessible_resources": [
        "style.css",
    "script.js",
    "jquery-2.0.3.min.js"
]
```

Can anyone explain why this isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is incorrect.  Your markup creates a span with a classname of grab_button, but your CSS code is matching a span that CONTAINS a descendant with that classname instead.  Your CSS selector code should be:

```
html body span.grab_button {
```

Or better yet, just:

```
.grab_button {
```

All that stuff preceding it is not needed and just makes it slower.

Comment: .grab_button on it's own doesn't work. Removing that whitespace doesn't work either... I had added the html body span in an attempt to make it more specific, hoping that would fix it, but it didn't.

Comment: From what I can tell, that should work.  Maybe someone else will chime in, but I don't see anything obvious.

Comment: I know. It should work. I managed to fix it by deleting the style sheet, and recreating it piece by piece, and reloading the extension after each change. No idea what was preventing it from working.